# Best way to upload many files to server

Tags: php, android, post, file-upload, get

I am developing an application in android that should send a web server an array of files (bitmap), its amount can vary.

I would like to know the best method I can use, if possible show me some example of this method.

Sending parameters must be something like this:

```
   {
        "name":"John",
        "id":9289392,
        "images":[ "image1", "image2", "image3" ]
    }
```

I already have knowledge of how to send a single file and how to get it using post method

Comment: What method are using to upload a single file, are uploading the file as is or encoding it with base64?

Comment: Have you tried using retrofit ? You can get all the images and store them in a list, then append the list to your Map payload when sending

Comment: Thanks @PeterstevUremgba for the tip, I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6sJdfQ5BwE&index=7&t=0s&list=PLpUMhvC6l7APq7y_FFfK-GEHvcUKqo6SC), I'll try and let you know if it work

Answer (score 0):

'multipart/form-data' supports multiple files. Here is an example in [Curl](https://medium.com/@petehouston/upload-files-with-curl-93064dcccc76)

From the link:

"To send upload request for multiple files, just add an additional -F option"

```
$ curl -F 'fileX=@/path/to/fileX' -F 'fileY=@/path/to/fileY' ... http://localhost/upload
```